# How to pass in a variable to the CSS grid repeat() function

Tags: javascript, css

I am attempting create a function which involves passing in a JS variable as a term in the CSS grid repeat() function. I do not know how to do this and cannot find google results for it, below is my attempt to estimate a possible implementation.

This is for the Odin Project's Etch-A-Sketch Project ([link](https://www.theodinproject.com/lessons/etch-a-sketch-project)), and everything is vanilla.

```
let test = 5;

function create() {
    for (let i = 0; i < gridsize; i++) {
    div = document.createElement('div')
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#39CCCC"
    div.style.border = "2px solid black"
    div.classList.toggle("mini")
    container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
})
    container.style.gridTemplate = "repeat(test, 1fr) / repeat(test, 1fr)"
    container.appendChild(div)
  }
}
```

No error messages seem to appear, and the JS containing the CSS function is simply ignored. The code runs perfectly fine as if that specific line was never written.

Comment: @randomSoul removing the quotes gives an uncaught syntax error.

Comment: Can you please reproduce the issue?

Comment: @weegee `repeat()` is a CSS value and not related to JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

Comment: @randomSoul `repeat()` is a CSS value and not related to JS : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat

Comment: @weegee isn't the code listed above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) strings to inject your variables into strings. Now you are outputting a string with the words *test* in them. And that will not be set on your element since it is not valid CSS.

You'll want to pass the values of the variable into the string.

```
container.style.gridTemplate = `repeat(${test}, 1fr) / repeat(${test}, 1fr)`;
```

Or if you cannot use Template Literals, concatenate the string.

```
container.style.gridTemplate = "repeat(" + test + ", 1fr) / repeat(" + test + ", 1fr)";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with css variables too

**template**

```
<div class="container" style="--columns-count:6; ...">...</div>
```

**style**

```
.container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns-count), 1fr)
}
```